# Clustering Documents in Python

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I understand that this question has been asked before and there are many links. I have gone through them, well most of them anyway but sadly failed to find a simple, and concise reponse. The number of documents are around 4800.

So here it goes.

I am using nltk for clustering a multitude of text documents. What I have done till now is

1. Parsing and Tokenization
2. Stopword and Stemming

The next step that I am doing is to find a TF-IDF vector for each document. So that I have n vectors of equal length for n documents.

Now I need to feed these vectors into my K-means function and let it rip.

Question is, am I doing it right?

Next question is related to code:

```
corpus = []
unique_terms = []


def TFIDF(document):
    start_time = time.time()
    word_tfidf = []
    for word in unique_terms:
        word_tfidf.append(collection.tf_idf(word,document))

    print time.time() - start_time
    return word_tfidf


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0
    corpus = cPickle.load(open('C:\\Users\\Salman\\Desktop\\Work\\NLP\\Corpus\\FB\\save-3.p', 'rb'))    ##read the corpus from file
    collection = nltk.TextCollection(corpus)
    unique_terms = list(set(collection))
    vectors = [numpy.array(TFIDF(f)) for f in corpus]
    print "Vectors created."
    print "First 10 words are", unique_terms[:10]
    print "First 10 stats for first document are", vectors[0][0:10]
```

I have already downloaded the corpus (list of vectors for each document before TF-IDF) to a file that I am reading in corpus.

Problem is that it's been 8 hours and this process hasn't yet completed. Have I missed anything here? Or in general, TF-IDF does take this amount of time.

Comment: Note that k-means is not the best idea for *sparse* vectors. In particular, you need to consider to improve your algorithm in a way it exploits sparsity when computing the distances.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote there is 4800 documents, but didn't specify length of documents. Anyway, 8 hours is really long time (TF_IDF with some standard euclidean distance is not too much expensive).

If you want to know whether it is counting, just look at load balance (e.g. `uptime` in linux). Most likely there is something wrong and you should look after logging info ...